# Should packages be 'use'd globally or from functions that need them?

Tags: perl

Apologies if this question isn't appropriate for StackOverflow. I suspect the answer is largely a matter of opinion (unless one of the style guides has a recommendation).

I have code that looks something like this

```
use File::Temp;

sub foo {
    ...
}
sub bar {
    ...
}
sub baz {
    my $fh = tempfile();
    ...
}
```

`baz` is the only subroutine that uses `File::Temp`, and I'm not using AutoLoader. Is it reasonable to put the `use` declaration inside `baz`, or should I leave it at the top of my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since (as chepner said), there is no difference technically, it really is a matter of style.

The pros of putting then all on top:

- Clear at first glance what all the direct module dependencies are
- Easier to maintain - if you need to move around code using the library, you don't need to remember to move the library.

  Please note that the same exact logic also applies to variable declarations, but in that case, the scoping concerns severely trump the "remember to move the declaration" concerns and therefore you should declare variables in the innermost possible scope as close to where they are used as possible.
- For esoteric cases where your own code contains complicated logic in `BEGIN{}` blocks that depends on all the libraries being loaded (e.g., call a specifically named method from ALL loaded libraries - which I have done) - you will have a bug if some library's `use` call is AFTER that `BEGIN{}` block

The cons of putting them all on top:

- One can possibly argue that this makes the code less readable since you need to seek out to the start of file to see what you imported from the module. Frankly, I don't believe that but I have heard it expressed and it has at least some merit.

Comment: And the con only applies to packages that export names automatically. Otherwise, `use foo;  foo::bar();` is required (and is always legal, even if `foo` does automatically export `bar`).

Comment: @chepner - I was going for the ones where you have EXPORT_OK and you manually import identifiers, mostly

Comment: To counter the cons, you can use the fully qualified name of the function (`File::Temp::tempfile()`) instead of the local imported alias. That makes the external reference explicit while the import is kept at the top.

Comment: Thanks for your second opinion, @DVK. It doesn't differ substantially from my first opinion.

Answer (score 4):

`use` is essentially the same as putting a `require` statement inside a `BEGIN` block, so it doesn't really matter where you put them; they are evaluated before any of the rest of your code.